# How to enable set -e around a script?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to do `bash <some options> script.sh`, so that the script is evaluated with the `set -euo pipeline` options enabled around it, without having to modify the script contents?

Answer (score 0):

`bash -c "set -euo pipefail ; script.sh"`